# Why assign statement is not updating with sum value?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

logic [31:0] sum_count;

//cnt0 and cnt1 are 24 bit signal

Case 1:

```
assign sum_count = (cnt0 & {8'b0,{24{en0}}}) + (cnt1 & {8'b0,{24{en1}}});
```

Case 2:

```
assign sum_count = (cnt0 & {8'b0,{24{en0}}});
```

For a condition where en0=1, en1=0; 
what I see in simulation is sum_count is remaining "0" while for case 2 sum_count is getting updated properly.
How can I debug the issue?

Comment: It works OK for me. Please submit an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: to debug the issue, you either need to generate a trace for relevant signals, or at least add `$display` to the code to see your value changes.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to write this would be

```
assign sum_count = (en0 ? cnt0 : 32'b0) + (en1 ? cnt1 : 32'b0)
```